# Rational Functional Tester MapFormatException

Tags: functional-programming, rft

couple of months ago I upgraded my instance of RFT to 8.5.0.1 I have recently started trying to create new Test scripts and noticed thet every time I tried to run a new script wheter recorded or calling parts of the framework library I am geting the following error:

> com.rational.test.ft.object.map.PbjectMapFormatException
>
> Could not read Object.Map [C:.......... path goes here .....] It may be missing or inthe wrong format

I am at a loss here. If you know of a solution I would appreciate it if you could enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a shared object map ? It looks like the object map is missing. Try creating a new RFT project and script with default object map to see if it solves the issue.